# How do I implement VST plugins in FMOD Ex?

Tags: c#, fmod, vst

The title says it all. I'm trying to implement VST plugins using FMOD Ex. The only guides I've been able to find have been for FMOD Studio, but not the actual coding implementation. I have the C++ documentation for FMOD, so I'm able to play sounds and even apply the stock DSP effects by translating it, but the documentation for VST plugins seemed very unclear to me (it's possible I'm just missing something).

I'm a great researcher when the resources are available, so even if someone can just point me in the right direction, it would be helpful (Google is not returning anything fruitful, possibly because the term 'fmod vst' is so vague).

Thanks!!

~Jake

Answer (score 0):

There is [VST.NET](https://vstnet.codeplex.com/) that allows you to build VST (2.x) plugins in .NET. I am not familiar with FMod but since you've tagged your question with 'C#' I assume you can interface it from .NET.

I suppose you could use VST.NET to create the VST plugin and implement the plugin's functionality (and UI?) with FMod.

Hope it helps.
Marc Jacobi (author of VST.NET)

Comment: Thanks Marc! I was actually looking into VST.NET last night, funnily enough. The problem I'm running into is the actual implementation of VST plugins in FMOD, though. Does VST.NET have the ability to read existing VST plugins?

Comment: 'Read'? VST.NET has the ability to load VST (managed or unmanaged) plugins and communicate with them. Look at the Host Sample application or the (Interop.Host) VstPluginContext.Create method. But what problems do you run into with the 'actual implementation in FMOD'?